# trying to understand this mov memory[register] instruction

Tags: ida

Windows 10, IDA Home, 64bit application compiled with Visual Studio.

I'm reverse engineering a crackme and i found this instruction :

```
  mov     cl, byte_51B000[eax]
  mov     byte_51B018[edx], cl
```

in these 2 byte_ location are null terminated strings.

I'm not sure to understand exactly what it's doing. Is it like an array index where byte_* is the array and [eax/edx] is the index ? i can't find this kind of syntax anywhere, is it IDA specific ?

Comment: This indeed is the same as `[eax+byte_51B000]`.

Comment: @usr2564301 thank you :)

Comment: Not adding an answer because I do not know if this is an IDA specific idiom. But – from memory – you can change the display using the hotkey for "Change offset type" (usually `o`).